# Get HTML tags from string with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I want to get html tag from the string.

I have tried this regex:

```
"<[\r\n ]*/?[\r\n ]*(.*?)[\r\n ]*/?[\r\n ]*>"
```

But it is also giving me:

```
< / table />
```

I don't want such wrong tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Regex is wrong tool for working with structutes like html, xml, etc. Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) for parsing html.

Comment: There are quite a lot of "how do I parse html with regex" questions, the general suggestion is to avoid doing that at all and use Html Agility Pack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Using `Regex` carefully and **limitedly** in just some certain `HTML` patterns would be OK.

Comment: @I4V I feel like I should start flagging such questions as duplicates of the one you linked. ;P

Comment: @Shaamaan: linked question is only for opening tag. I want opening and closing both the tags.

Comment: Same thing. Seriously, Regex is nice and all, and can even be used for limited HTML scenarios, but generally you want an XML parser. Or that Agility Pack people keep linking.

Answer (score 1):

Try `</?[^>/]*>|<[^>/]*/>` or `</?[^>/]+>|<[^>/]+/>`. Google is your friend as well.

Comment: From question: *But it is also giving me: `< / table />` I don't want such wrong tags.*

Comment: I've amended my answer to accommodate for the issue pointed out, @I4V.

Comment: What about this valid html? `<html><body><img src='#' /></body></html>`

Comment: @ErikAllik : It is not giving me <img src='#' /> tag

Comment: @I4V: fixed, again :)

Comment: @ErikAllik but it returns attributes too.

Comment: I am ok with tag with attributes.

Comment: Well, it's a known thing that real HTML cannot be reliably parsed with regular expressions anyway and an XML parser should be used instead; I should have mentioned it in the answer.

Comment: @ChandniShah: you should seriously consider using an XML parser: `<img src="foo/bar.jpg"/>` won't be handled by my regexps either.

Comment: @ErikAllik Or better, as mentioned in comments: HtmlAgilityPack.